# App.MobileService.LoginAsync fails to show dialog on select machine -> Mind Blown

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services

Just wondering if anyone might be able to point me in the right direction here.

```
user = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(provider)
```

this is the line of code in question.  The problem is; this works fine on 2/3 test machines (All Windows 10), the dialog is displayed and the program operates as expected. on the third machine however, the dialog does not display.  I have wrapped the function in a try catch block and I am catching all exceptions that I then route to a MessageDialog to display on the screen.  the messages are never shown, as though the try succeeded, but the function exits on that line exactly and throws no exceptions.  I am using MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount as my provider.

Code redacted to highlight the error, the full code returns a boolean value for success/failure. All traces past the failing line do not appear, so the function is definitely exiting at the specified line.

```
try
{
//This line fails on a single machine out of three
user = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(provider)
}
catch(Exception e)
{
//when it fails, this does not trigger, and no traces after this point
//appear until outside the function
MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog(e.ToString());
await msg.ShowAsync();
}
```

and just to make things really weird...message dialogs prior to this point in the code work just fine...

I suspect that the security of the machine in question is blocking the login (windows defender), but I really have no idea where to look for this, or even how to test the problem further.  Any ideas as to what would prevent this single machine from displaying the Microsoft login window, or ideas on further debugging would be appreciated.

Comment: and yes, the computer in question has run the software successfully  in the past (this very same code in fact).  Baffled...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. Regardless of whether dialog popped up, did the login succeed or not?

Comment: I does not, as soon as that line hits, it exits the function without triggering a message dialog or a login window...there is something unique to this machine completely blocking the popup...i have tested the code on several machines now...it works every time on all but this one machine (which happens to be the giant tablet we use for demos).  It has to be something specific to this computer, viral or possibly a setting in windows 10 perhaps.  I will probably just put a fresh image on...I would however like to solve this, as it is likely our help desk will  run into this in the future.

Comment: Ok...it seems to definitly be a setting on the windows account.  After creating a new account on the problem machine the software works as intented.  Whatever setting it is, it is not roaming as the problem account works fine on other machines.  So now the question is...what system level account setting could prevent a windows login popup in an app.

Answer (score 1):

You are not awaiting the response from the Async reply.  This means that you will have an ordering and concurrency issue - sometimes it will work, and sometimes it won't and it's all in the timing.

You need:

```
var user = await client.LoginAsync(provider);
```

Comment: Ah, typo'd...it is actually awaited, thanks for the response, ill fix the OP

Comment: So, the LoginAsync() has two methods - one pops up a webview and then captures the response (which you are using) - this can be affected by a number of things.  The other is to integrate the provider SDK, then pass the token received to the azure mobile apps backend (called client flow). This is generally how I recommend you do things as it provides a "more native" experience.  If the security settings on the client machine are causing issues, this will be the way around that as well.

Comment: Originally I was using the windows live sdk for this and passing the auth token to azure.  Then we upgraded to windows 10 and the live sdk was marked obsolete. I responded with the approach you see in the OP.  Is there a different windows account auth sdk you would recommend for a windows 10 store app?

Comment: The OP uses the "web view" mechanism.  My recommendation is to use Microsoft Account with a client flow.  Auth with Microsoft Account as normal - get the authenticationToken (or access_token), and use a client-flow with loginAsync.  Reference is in the book http://aka.ms/zumobook in chapter 2.